# User Login not working, query issue ( PDO, MySQL, PHP )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I went on rampage of changing from the about to be deprecated MySQL, I'm currently starting with my user login system which I am unable to login after changing the querys and such.
Here is what I've got so far.

As there aren't any errors given AT ALL, It's not redirecting me to my index.php.

login.php -> after loging redirects to index.php

What could be wrong with my current login code?

- includes/db.php

  ```
  try { 
      $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=timeline_database", 'root', ''); 
  }
  catch( PDOException $e ) 
  { 
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  ```
- includes/Wall_Updates.php

  ```
  class Wall_Updates {
          private $db;

  public  function __construct ( $db ){
      $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function User_Login($_iUsername,$_iPassword) {
      $md5_password = md5($_iPassword);

      $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = ? AND _iPassword = ? AND _iStatus = 1");
      $sth->execute(array($_iUsername, $md5_password));

      if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
          $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          return $row['_iD'];
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  public function User_Registration($_iPassword,$_iEmail,$_iNickname,$_iUsername) {
      $md5_password   = md5($_iPassword);

      $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iEmail = ? ");
      $sth->execute(array($_iEmail));

      if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {
          $sth1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (_iPassword,_iEmail,_iNickname,_iUsername) VALUES ( :_iPassword, :_iEmail, :_iNickname, :_iUsername ");
              $sth1->execute(array(':_iPassword' => $_iPassword,
                                   ':_iEmail'    => $_iEmail,
                                   ':_iNickname' => $_iNickname,
                                   ':_iUsername' => $_iUsername
                                  ));

          $sth3 = $db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users where _iUsername = ?");
              $sth3->execute(array($_iUsername));

          $sth2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO friends (friend_one,friend_two,role) VALUES ( :rowiD, :_rowiD, :me ");
              $sth2->execute(array(':rowiD' => $row['_iD'],
                                   ':rowiD' => $row['_iD'],
                                   ':me' => me 
                                  ));

              $row = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          return $row['_iD'] ;
      } else {
              return false;
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- login.php

  ```
  include_once 'includes/db.php';
  include_once 'includes/Wall_Updates.php';
  error_reporting( E_ALL );

  session_start();
  if(!empty($_SESSION['_iD'])) {
      header("location:index.php");
  }

  $Wall = new Wall_Updates( $db );

  $login_error = '';
  if(!empty($_POST['_iUsername']) && !empty($_POST['_iPassword'])){
      if ( strlen($_POST['_iUsername'])>0 && strlen($_POST['_iPassword'])>0) {
      $login = $Wall->User_Login( $_POST['_iUsername'],$_POST['_iPassword'] );
          if( $login ){
              $_SESSION['_iD'] = $login;
              header("location: index.php");
          } else {
              $login_error="<div class='error' style='margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: -8px;' ><span class='error'>Email or Password is invalid</span></div><br>";
          }
      }
  }


  html begins <?php echo $login_error; ?></div>
  <form method="post" action="" name="login">
      <input class="_iUsernameClass" type="text" placeholder="_iUsername" name="Username" id="login._iEmail">
      <input class="_iPasswordClass" type="password" placeholder="_iPassword"  name="Password" id="login._iPassword">
      <button class="primary" type="submit"></button>
  </form> html ends
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see is that you need to use [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). Try adhering to this structure for your query builds:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("
  SELECT _iD
  FROM users
  WHERE _iUsername = :username
  AND _iPassword = :password");
$sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(":password", $md5_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns id or false
```

Just a side note to keep in mind:

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Returns only one record, and:

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Returns all (multiple) records.

*BTW, I did not review all of your code due to time constraints. This is only the first issue I encountered.*

Comment: Now I understand the use for bindValue, but when is the correct time to use the question mark such as "_iUsername = ? ".

Comment: You don't use the question mark as a placeholder. You use the colon (:) and string combo passed from bindValue(). e.g. `:username` or you can label it as you wish... e.g. `:_iUsername` in `$sth->bindValue(":_iUsername", $_iUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Follow the examples on the bindValue() documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php - You can use the data_type parameter (e.g. PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT, PDO::PARAM_BOOL) to bind each value's explicit data type for the parameter. See PDO's Predefined Constants section: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php